# DGCharts Y-axis labels are not aligned to left

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios-charts

I am using [DGCharts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and Y-axis labels aren't aligned to the left but are aligned to the right.

[image]

By default

```
chartView.leftAxis.labelAlignment = .left
```

I tried explicitly setting `.left` to  `labelAlignment` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, neither labelAlignment left nor right works with `labelPosition == .outsideChart`. The chart always takes left with `.insideChart` and right with `.outsideChart`.

In case you just want a little spacing between leftAxis's label and the chart content, you can try this:

```swift
chartView.leftAxis.xOffset = 8
```

Or custom `IndexAxisValueFormatter` with spacings.

```swift
class MyYAsixFormatter: IndexAxisValueFormatter {
    override func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return "\(value)    "
    }
}
...
chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = MyYAsixFormatter()
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, but i've already tried that. I want to achieve exactly what 
labelAlignment = .left should do. I want the labels to be aligned to the left. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it's quite impossible. I hope someone will give you the correct solution.